# Cloth Simulation. How to limit pressure without collision object

Tags: cloth-simulation

For example this object.I want to stop spreading pressure here.

[image]

When I use another object it is fine but the shape changes.

[image]

When I'm using *Cloth Simulation > Pressure*, how to spread pressure equally on surface?

[image]

It is easy to do it using  *Loop Tool > Bridge* , but it works only with simple shapes.

[image]

Also I already found solution how to do it using *Weight Paint*, but it complex if I want to do this "thing" with multiple objects.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please be so kind and complete your question with more information that can help us understand how you have set it up. It will be difficult to give a clear answer with the pictures alone. Show what exactly you have done here and possibly share your blend file with the help of https://blend-exchange.com/. Thank you for your understanding!